# Convert JIntArray to Array of Object

Tags: arrays, delphi, java-native-interface

```
function Java_com_erm_controller_ARMReports_S35(PEnv: PJNIEnv; Obj: JObject; ex_UserRowID, ex_BSID : Integer; ex_RevalDate : JString;
               ex_AFS, ex_HTM, ex_HFT : Boolean;
               ex_IsMcCaulay_PNL: Boolean;
               ex_Maturity, ex_Scale : JIntArray 
               ): Integer; stdcall; export;
var objRpt : TARMReports;
I : Integer;
Len : JInt; //just a renamed delphi integer
aMaturity:array of Integer;
aScale:array of Integer;

begin
   DLLErrorLog('CASH -S35');
  objRpt := TARMReports.Create; JVM := TJNIEnv.Create(PEnv); ex_RevalDate_J := JVM.JStringToString(ex_RevalDate);

  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Maturity);
  SetLength(aMaturity, Len);
  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Scale);
  SetLength(aScale, Len);

  DLLErrorLog('ex_Maturity Length'+ intToStr(Len));

  for I := 0 to Len-1 do
    begin
      PEnv^.GetIntArrayRegion(PEnv, ex_Maturity, I, Len, @aMaturity[I]);
      DLLErrorLog('ex_Maturity '+ IntToStr(aMaturity[I]));

      PEnv^.GetIntArrayRegion(PEnv, ex_Scale, I, Len, @aScale[I]);
      DLLErrorLog('ex_Scale '+ IntToStr(aScale[I]));
    end;


 Result := objRpt.S35(ex_UserRowID, ex_BSID,  ex_RevalDate_J,
               ex_AFS, ex_HTM, ex_HFT ,
               ex_IsMcCaulay_PNL,
               aMaturity, aScale
               );

   DLLErrorLog('CASH2 Ends -S35');

  JVM.Free; objRpt.Free;
end;
```

Need to convert `ex_Maturity`, `ex_Scale` to objects to Delphi's `Array of Integer`.

Now while calling from Java it throws  **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

While printing in Log array values are getting . Please suggest us to work for me.

Comment: -1 You have stated a requirement, but you need to ask a question. I suggest a look at the [faq]

Comment: What is the context of this code? I am sceptical it's going to work because it looks like a flat function, and the Delphi/Java bridge presupposes an OOP context - JObject isn't an actual Java object, but a Delphi interface that wraps a Java object. As such, all the object parameters need to be declared as raw pointers, not wrapper interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, depending on what, exactly your JIntArray *is*.

Firstly, if its an array of *int* (as in the primitive java type) then a get the length of the array via JNI, allocate a delphi array of integers and then get JNI to copy the data from the java array

```
Uses
  AndroidAPI.JNI;
Var
  Len:JNIInt; //just a renamed delphi integer
  aMaturity:array of integer;
begin
  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Maturity);

  //allocate the receiving array
  SetLength(aMaturity, Len);

  //now get the array data - note we are passing the address of the first element 
  //not the address of the array itself!
  PEnv^.GetIntArrayRegion(PEnv, ex_Maturity, 0, Len, @aMaturity[0]);

  //do stuff
end;
```

If you are dealing with an array of Integer (thats the Java class "Integer") then you need to get the array of objects from JNI one element at a time and use TJNIResolver to get the raw value;

```
Uses
  AndroidAPI.JNI, AndroidAPI.JNIBridge;
Var
  Len:JNIInt; //just a renamed delphi integer
  Count:Integer;
  Current:JNIObject;
  CurrentValue:integer;
  aMaturity:array of integer;
begin
  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Maturity);

  //allocate the receiving array
  SetLength(aMaturity, Len);

  For Count:=0 to Len-1 do
    begin
      Current:=PEnv^.GetObjectArrayElement(PEnv, ex_Maturity, Count);

      if assigned(Current) then
        begin
          CurrentValue:=TJNIResolver.GetRawValueFromJInteger(Current);
          //Yes, you can inline this but the point is, here you do stuff with 
          //the element
          aMaturity[Count]:=CurrentValue;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Obviously the first method is much faster as crossing the JNI barrier is *slow* and you are only doing it once, whereas with the array of Java Integers you are doing it multiple times for each *element*.

You should also watch out for errors - I'm not checking for Java exceptions at any point which could crash and burn your app if you don't deal with them.

Edit : The OP has ready my answer and tried to work with it, which is nice.  They have gotten a out of bounds exception in their code.

```
function Java_com_erm_controller_ARMReports_S35(PEnv: PJNIEnv; Obj: JObject; ex_UserRowID, ex_BSID : Integer; ex_RevalDate : JString;
           ex_AFS, ex_HTM, ex_HFT : Boolean;
           ex_IsMcCaulay_PNL: Boolean;
           ex_Maturity, ex_Scale : JIntArray 
           ): Integer; stdcall; export;
var objRpt : TARMReports;
    I : Integer;
    Len : JInt; //just a renamed delphi integer
    aMaturity:array of Integer;
    aScale:array of Integer;
begin
   DLLErrorLog('CASH -S35');
  objRpt := TARMReports.Create; JVM := TJNIEnv.Create(PEnv); ex_RevalDate_J := JVM.JStringToString(ex_RevalDate);

  //you only have 1 length defined and possibly different array lengths
  //process arrays seperately
  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Maturity);
  SetLength(aMaturity, Len);
  DLLErrorLog('ex_Maturity Length'+ intToStr(Len));

  //only call this once, also watch the parameters you are passing in 
  PEnv^.GetIntArrayRegion(PEnv, ex_Maturity, 0, Len, @aMaturity[0]);


  Len:=PEnv^.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_Scale);
  SetLength(aScale, Len);

  DLLErrorLog('ex_Scale Length'+ intToStr(Len));
  PEnv^.GetIntArrayRegion(PEnv, ex_Scale, 0, Len, @aScale[0]);


  Result := objRpt.S35(ex_UserRowID, ex_BSID,  ex_RevalDate_J,
                 ex_AFS, ex_HTM, ex_HFT ,
                 ex_IsMcCaulay_PNL,
                 aMaturity, aScale
                 );

  DLLErrorLog('CASH2 Ends -S35');

  JVM.Free; objRpt.Free;
end;
```

What you were doing was getting the length twice, setting the delphi arrays correctly but then looping over them both in the same loop not taking into account that they could be different lengths.  Your call to *getinarrayregion* was also passing the complete length in for aScale on the second parameter for both calls - if you really want to get each one in a loop like that then you need to pass the count and a length of 1 to only return 1 element - this is most likely what was causing the exception.

If you want to report the contents then create a procedure to do it, rather than using a loop inside your current procedure, you would have to copy and paste the loop to do it otherwise which is, franky bad coding practice and we don't want that now do we?

**Sarcasm on**
Not that expecting someone who has tried to help you to correct the your code rather than actually *understanding* the problem is any better, but ho hum.
**Sarcasm off**

Comment: Thanks for ur response , Your 1st set of code getting array values from java and printing the array values in log.   Even though while calling the delphi (dll) function from java it throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer to reflect what you did wrong, hopefully you can see the issue that needed to be corrected.

Comment: Can u please help to convert for the array of String ... From java String[]  will be passed and in delphi function array of String ..

Comment: Thats a new question, if you start a new topic I will have a look and see.